# Printing a table of numbers from a file, then averaging each column

Tags: python, loops, file

I am trying to create a proper code in Python. I have created a text file called "numbers" and then have python list out the numbers before averaging them out. There are 2 columns of numbers, and they are in 'float' format.

So far, this is what I have come up with:

```
def main():

     outfile = open("numbers.txt", 'r')

     numRow = 0.0
     total1 = 0.0
     total2 = 0.0

     for line in outfile:
          col1, col2 = line[:-1].split(" ")
          col1 = eval(col1)
          col2 = eval(col2)
          print(col1, col2)
          print()
          total1 = col1 + 1
          total2 = col2 + 1
          numRow = numRow + 1

     print("Your total for column 1 is:",total1)
     print("Your total for column 2 is:",total2)
     print()
     print("The average of column 1 is:",total1/numRow)
     print("The average of column 2 is:",total2/numRow)

main()
```

I am not getting the correct totals, and obviously averages.

Comment: `total1 = col1 + 1` sets total1 to the value of col1 plus 1. You probably don't want that.

Comment: would i adjust both totals to: 'total1 = total1 + col1' and 'total2 = total2 + col2' ?

Comment: Also try posting a small sample of your text file so we can verify solutions

Comment: looks like i made the mistake of using "+ 1" on both totals instead of "+ total1" and "+ total2". I am now getting the correct totals and averages. Thanks a bunch @MichaelButscher

Comment: I suggest you break this down into smaller pieces. Try writing a program that totals a single column of numbers. and prints the total and average.

Comment: Thanks @Code-Apprentice, i did a breakdown but with just separating the numbers before the actual totals and averages. I appreciate the advice for future programs though. Sounds like the best way to do it.

Comment: I use that approach all the time, especially in larger systems. Also, when things don't work out the way you want, then you need to debug your code to figure out why. [This article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) has some great tips to get you started. GL to you in your programming journey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
def main():

     outfile = open("numbers.txt", 'r')

     numRow = 0.0
     total1 = 0.0
     total2 = 0.0

     for line in outfile:
          # you can drop the argument to split as that is the default
          col1, col2 = line[:-1].split()
          col1 = eval(col1)
          col2 = eval(col2)
          print(col1, col2)
          print()
          # use the += operator
          total1 += col1
          total2 += col2
          numRow +=  1

     print("Your total for column 1 is:",total1)
     print("Your total for column 2 is:",total2)
     print()
     print("The average of column 1 is:",total1/numRow)
     print("The average of column 2 is:",total2/numRow)

main()
```

Comment: Thanks Robert King! That's exactly what i needed to do.